# Configuring FTP Server in IIS for remote access in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: iis, iis-7, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have configured an FTP server in IIS 6. I can access it by using ftp://localhost/. When I try I accessing it using static IP instead of localhost in a remote location, the page doesn't open. I am using Amazon EC2 instance. I have opened all ports for ICMP so I can ping to the static IP and port 21, 20, 1025-7000 are opened. I can open the page even if I disable the windows firewall. What changes must I make for it to work remotely ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the site binding listens on the public IP for FTP, and not just 127.0.0.1.  Try testing locally using ftp://{your_public_ip} to confirm that it's setup to listen on that IP.  If it works locally but not remotely, then a firewall or proxy server in-between is blocking it.

Also, try *briefly* to disable the Windows firewall to confirm that it's not fighting with you.  Or, better yet, enable logging and check the logs after a failed attempt.  That way you don't have to disable the whole firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today, so maybe my answer will still be helpful for someone.
All I needed to do was to add a security rule in my EC2 dashboard. The steps are:

1. Go to EC2 dashboard
2. Select *Security Groups* in the right panel
3. Select *HTTP* rule in *Inbound Rules* tab
4. Click *Add Rule* and then *Apply Rule Changes*